# Unable to send or troubleshoot UDP packet in Python 2.7

Tags: python, udp

I am attempting to send packets to my "wifi lights" lighting system (like Philips Hue). I have documentation here that describes needing to send udp packets to my "bridge" using port 8899 which I have the IP address for.

> All UDP Commands are 3 Bytes. 
>   i.e. to turn all RGBW COLOR Wifi Lights Smart  lights to ON then send
>   the TCP/IP UDP packet of:  0x42 0x00 0x55

The only way I could figure how to do in python was to chain them together as MESSAGE below. sendto() requires a string and won't accept hex or int.

```
import socket
UDP_IP1 = '192.168.0.104'
UDP_PORT = 8899
MESSAGE = str(0x410055)#0x410055

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

However I consistently get this error.

```
  File "C:\3_test\wifilight_py.py", line 37, in <module>
    sock.sendto(str(e), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

This despite windows firewall being disabled completely (windows 7 / Python 2.7).

I am at my wit's end, I am not sure how I should troubleshoot this. I have Wireshark installed but it provides a huge dump of information and nothing related.

Comment: And what is the problem? Seems your question is truncated.

Comment: i suspect you need to do a `sock.bind(('',0))` before you call the `sendto()` function

Comment: Thanks adrianX, I tried that with no luck.
Lorenz, broadcasting should be doing something (e.g. turning lights off) but it's doing nothing, or just giving an error. 

I wonder how I could go about sniffing traffic for troubleshooting purposes...